# How to treat uncolored edges in constructing fan in edge coloring algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have problems implementing Misra & Gris edge coloring algorithm. I have simple question - how to treat uncolored edges in construction of maximal fan?

Is uncolored a free color on all vertices, free only on vertices which are uncolored(we treat uncolored as separate color) or somehow else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't matter (after careful read of all proofs and writing the code). However using uncolored edges can uncolor edges by accident so one need to track it in such setup. Also the maximal fan would be bigger in such case.